# How can I unsubcribe via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, list, unsubscriber

This is what I am using for a 1 click unsubcribe:

```
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$SubscriberTestEmail=$_GET["subscriberKey"]; 
$listID =$_GET["ListID"]; 
$SubscriberTestEmail="xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$listID = "XXXX";
$subPatch->props = array("EmailAddress" => $SubscriberTestEmail, "Status" => "Active");
$subPatch->props = array("ID" =>$listID, "Status" => "Unsubscribed","SubscriberKey" => $SubscriberTestEmail);
```

Is there a way to create a one click unsubscribe for all lists that have the same sender profile?

Comment: Please explain what you are using exactly as Salesforce technology, what method you are calling, ... The more you are precise the more we can help you.

Comment: Hi Martin,  I am using method SOAP and what I need is to to retrive all lists a user has. I found this link, but its not working: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_all_lists_a_subscriber_is_on.htm  . Do you have any other way of doing it?